# "I like phones by Apple" or "I like phones made by Apple"?

Tags: phrase-choice

Tell me please which one of the following sentences sounds the most natural.

> I like phones **by** Apple.
>
> I like phones **made by** Apple.

If neither sounds natural, how would you say it?

Answer (score 1):

Both sound fine.

You could also say "I like Apple phones" or "I like iPhones".

"I like iPhones" is probably the most common but if you specifically want to say "Apple" or if Apple has a phone that isn't an iPhone then feel free to pick from any of the other options. There is hardly any difference and, to me, they all sound the same in terms of how natural they are.